# React component doesnt execute in function called on onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First I call Countries component from App, passing the showCountry (where the CountryDetails wont execute)

```
const showCountry = (country) => {
    console.log(country)
    return (
      <CountryDetails country={country} />
    )
  }
...

<Countries countries={countries} filter={filter} handleClick={showCountry}/>
```

Countries list with a button next to each country to show country details

```
<ul>
  {toShow.map(country => <li>{country.name} <Button country={country} handleClick={handleClick}/></li>)}
</ul>
```

My button component, where I ran into some trouble trying to pass the country data to the event handler. Ended up with the solution below (no idea is this good practice)

```
const Button = ({ handleClick, country}) => (
  <button onClick={() => handleClick(country)}>
    show
  </button>
)

const CountryDetails = props => {
  const country = props.country
  console.log('country details..')
  return ...
}
```

Function showCountry does get executed with the correct data that is passed to it, but doesnt execute CountryDetails.

Sorry for long post, and any feedback for better practices are welcome!

Comment: Returning a JSX element to a clickHandler - `handleClick={showCountry}` does nothing. I'm guessing this should probably update state or something? It'd be best if you could post a more complete example of what you're code looks like.

Comment: You need a basic React concept: conditional rendering. The flow is: 1. user clicks button 2. state changes 3. component re-renders, and based on new state, conditionally rendered component is now visible